# Using Regex to extract Data to different Columns in Pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm working with the following DataFrame column containing `Date |TimeStamp | Name | Message` as a string

```
59770        [08/10/18, 5:57:43 PM] Luke: Message
59771   [08/10/18, 5:57:48 PM] Luke: Message
59772     [08/10/18, 5:57:50 PM] Luke: Message
```

I use the following function to capture the Date.

```py
def getdate(x):
    res = re.search("\d\d/\d\d/\d\d",x)
```

and the following code to capture the rest of the data (TimeStamp | Name | Message) into columns:

```py
df['Data'].str.extract(r'\s*(.{10})](.*):(.*)')
```

Is there a workaround to capture and extract all 4 entities together?

Please Advise

Comment: If you could change  the  data in file  you could convert  file to a csv and then used  from pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative you could use regex [`named groups`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) together with pandas [`extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html).

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame(
    ["        [08/10/18, 5:57:43 PM] Luke: Message",
     "   [08/10/18, 5:57:48 PM] Luke: Message",
     "     [08/10/18, 5:57:50 PM] Luke: Message"])

print(df)

regex = re.compile(\
    r"(?P<date>\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}),\s*"
    r"(?P<timestamp>\d+:\d+:\d+\s[AP]M)\]\s+"
    r"(?P<name>.+?):\s*"
    r"(?P<message>.+)$"
    )

df_out = df[0].str.extractall(regex).droplevel(1)
print(df_out)
```

Output from *df_out*

```
       date   timestamp  name  message
0  08/10/18  5:57:43 PM  Luke  Message
1  08/10/18  5:57:48 PM  Luke  Message
2  08/10/18  5:57:50 PM  Luke  Message
```

Comment: Well this is exactly where I'm stuck at, apparently your method and mine include a part of some messages in the name column as well. Here's an example `Luke: Message.... `

Comment: @Luke Try to make the `name` capture non greedy. I have edit the answer.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Would you care to explain what you changed?

Comment: Changed the name capture from `?P<name>.+` to `?P<name>.+?` making it non greedy. This way the regex engine will matche as few characters as possible until reaches the first `:`.

Answer (score 0):

I change the format of each line as follow in file "file.csv" :

```
08/10/18, 5:57:43 PM, Luke, Message
```

And then used from this code to read it as data frame :

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
 print (df)
```

OutPut:

```
  Date         time   name       msg
```

0  08/10/18   5:57:43 PM   Luke   Message

Suppose your data is in file "file_data.txt" as follow format:

```
  [08/10/18, 5:57:43 PM] Luke: Message
  [08/10/18, 5:57:48 PM] Luke: Message
  [08/10/18, 5:57:50 PM] Luke: Message
```

you can use from thease sed commands to convert data to csv :

```
 sed -i "s/]/,/"  file_data.txt
 sed -i "s/\[//"  file_data.txt
 sed -i "s/:/,/"  file_data.txt
```

Comment: How do you change the format? It's actually a `.txt` file not `.csv`

Comment: No matters the format of file you can  change it by sed.

Comment: Yields an error `sed: 1: "Chat.txt": invalid command code C
`